# looping an associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, infusionsoft

I have an associative array from a csv

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Firstname] => john [ Surname] => Smith [ Address] => Flat 1 [ Postcode] => 12345 [ Telephone] => 07777 777 777  [Email] => xxx@xxxx.xom ) [1] => Array ( [Firstname] => Robert [ Surname] => Smith [ Address] => 15 Glebe Stree [ Postcode] => g54er [ Telephone] => 07888787887 [Email] => xxxx@xxx.com )
```

What I am tying to do is loop through the array and create a connection string and insert the users

```
$conDat = array('FirstName' => 'john',
          'LastName'  => 'Smith',
          'Address'     => 'Flat 1',
          'Postcode' => '12345',
          'Telephone' => '07777 777 777',
          'Email' => 'xxx@xxxx.xom'); 


);


$conID = $app->addCon($conDat);
```

The problem I am having is iterating through and putting the key and value into the connection Data and sending it. This is what I have so far.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($csv);$i++){
    $c=0;
    foreach($csv[$i] as $key=>$value){
        $c++;
        echo $key;echo $value;
        if($c<count($csv[$i])) echo " ";

    }
}
?>
```

EDIT:

so this is what I am trying to achieve

```
for($i=0;$i<count($csv);$i++){
    $c=0;
    foreach($csv[$i] as $key=>$value){
        $c++;

        $conData[] = array($key => $value);


        if($c<count($csv[$i])) {

$conID = $app->addCon($conDat);

    }

}
```

Comment: What "connection" are you talking about?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you expect?

Comment: http://help.infusionsoft.com/api-docs/dataservice this is the api if you look at the add method. i need to loop through every user and insert it

Comment: Very poorly worded question.  I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, or what form of answer you are expecting.  To start with, you need to explain what the function `addCon` does, and whether it adds data column by column, or row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing i think this might be it:

```
foreach($csv as $conection){
    foreach($conection as $key=>$value){
        $conData = array($key => $value);
        $conID = $app->addCon($conData);
    }
}
```